# can't iterate over an array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fetch

iam traying to iterate over an array in js but it's not work and and i always get length equal 0 and when i try to access elements by index i get undefined but when i try to print my array by clg it worked well here is my code

```
function getData(url) {
    let arr = []
    fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            arr[index] = data[index].content
        }
    })
        console.log(arr)
}
```

with `console.log (arr)`  this the result

```
[]
0: "any"
1: "any"
2: "any"
3: "any"
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

but with  `console.log (arr[0])`  i got

```
undefined
```

i want to get result from fetch and convert it to array and iterate over this array

Comment: fetch is *asynchronous* - so your `console.log(arr)` runs before the request is made - the reason you can see anything in the array though is because by the time you inspect it in the console, you've filled the array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: jaromanda so i should mak delay ? or what

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `Promise` and the `arr` too. Then in a `.then` set the referenc you want.

```
function getData(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
      arr[index] = data[index].content
    }
    return arr;
  })
}

getData(url).then(contents => { /*... do whatever you want */ });
```

You can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), so itt will be easier to manage callbacks

```
async function getData(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => data.map(d => d.content));
}

const contents = await getData(url);
for(const content of contents){
 /*... do whatever you want */ 
}
```

Comment: is there is away to get array outside function to use it in all my program because those functions return promises not var